# Can't throttle function with useState hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash, addeventlistener, react-hooks

I'm trying to throttle an event "wheel" on scroll using a lodash library for my React app with no success.

I need to listen to e.deltaY from scroll input in order to detect its scroll direction. To add a listener I wrote a React hook that accepts an event name and a handler function.

**Base implementation**

```
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const handleSections = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  const handleWheel = _.throttle(e => {
    handleSections();
  }, 10000);

  useEventListener("wheel", handleWheel);
```

**My useEventListener hook**

```
function useEventListener(e, handler, passive = false) {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener(e, handler, passive);

    return function remove() {
      window.removeEventListener(e, handler);
    };
  });
}
```

Working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/throttledemo-hkf7n

My goal is to throttle this scroll event in order to have less events firing and to have a few seconds to scroll my page programmatically (`scrollBy()`, par example).
At this moment throttling seem to not work so I'm getting lots of scroll events all at once

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you can call `_.throttle()` on a function, you get back a new function that "manages" the invocation of the original function. Whenever the wrapper function is called, the wrapper checks if enough time passed, and if so it calls the original function.

If `_.throttle()` is called multiple times, it returns a new function that doesn't have the "history" of calling the function. It will then call the original function again and again.

In your case the wrapped function is regenerated on each render. Wrap the call to `_.throttle()` with `useCallback` ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/throttledemo-ukz5m)):

```js
const { useState, useCallback, useEffect } = React;

function useEventListener(e, handler, cleanup, passive = false) {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener(e, handler, passive);

    return function remove() {
      cleanup && cleanup(); // optional specific cleanup for the handler
    
      window.removeEventListener(e, handler);
    };
  }, [e, handler, passive]);
}

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const handleWheel = useCallback(_.throttle(() => {
    setCount(count => count + 1);
  }, 10000, { leading: false }), [setCount]);

  useEventListener("wheel", handleWheel, handleWheel.cancel); // add cleanup to cancel throttled calls

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Event fired {count} times</h1>
      <h2>It should add +1 to cout once per 10 seconds, doesn't it?</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Tried to find this oversight but couldn't succeed, thank you! One question: is this an expected behavior that my scroll event happens one more time after 10 seconds? The goal is to catch only the first scroll event per _n_ seconds

Comment: Welcome. You want to call the handler only once after 10 seconds, and then stop? So if I scrolling for 30 seconds, the count would go to 1, after 10 seconds, and that it?

Comment: Tnank you! I expected to have throttle cutting down my scroll events. Say, in 32s scrolling session I'd get 3 events (1 every 10s)

Comment: So you don't want to the 1st call (the leading call at 0). That can be easily solved by using { leading: false } in _.throttle(). Or you want the leading (at the start of 10 seconds), and don't want the trailing (after 10 seconds).

Comment: I've changed the leading option to `false`. Try replacing it with `trailing: false` to see what option is better for you.

Comment: Never read through all of the docs :D Thank you, that's exactly what I needed!

Comment: Add throttle cancel on remove, to clear pending calls. This will prevent the last throttle from calling setState after component was unmounted.